# Dependency injection, polymorphism and OOP patterns (MVC, command and others)

Tags: java, oop, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, dependency-injection

**Intro:** I work with Java EE 7 with glassfish 4 (so CDI container is weld). This is the third day I am reading about dependency injection and its principles, so if you find my question stupid just explain what I misunderstand.... This question rises from [How to implement command pattern via CDI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152373/how-to-implement-command-pattern-via-cdi)

**Problem:** 
Four books were read. What I see that DI is a nice technology it makes our code clear.

Two main principles that I see are: First main principle - CDI container injects instances of certain classes. Second main principle is "Just remember: "There can be only one." (Weld reference (WR)).

So the problem appears when we start actively use polymorphism. I don't know how others do MVC but I have a lot of controllers. Besides I want to try new design and divide all application into components, each component with its controllers and actions. In ideal each component can be developed **by independent programmers**. And when we use no CDI everything is ok. Each component has its controllers, and actions. For example 10 components can have SaveAction class. It's obvious that these classes are private and can be used only in their package. And here we have a big problem. We must clearly distinguish what instances of Action class (from ALL classes that implement this interface) we want to use.

From WR:

To fix anambiguous dependency, either:

> - introduce a qualifier to distinguish between the two implementations of the bean type,
> - disable one of the beans by annotating it@Alternative,
> - move one of the implementations to a module that is not in the classpath of the  module with the injection point, or
> - disable one of two @Alternative  beans that are trying to occupy the same space, usingbeans.xml.

How can I follow these advices if I use dozens of action classes? I tried to use producer method. But without new (new we can't use otherwise controllers and actions can't inject other beans). In this situation Weld say to do like this.

```
@Produces @Preferred @SessionScoped
public PaymentStrategy getPaymentStrategy(CreditCardPaymentStrategy ccps,
    CheckPaymentStrategy cps,PayPalPaymentStrategy ppps) {
    switch (paymentStrategy) {
       case CREDIT_CARD: return ccps;
       case CHEQUE: return cps;
       case PAYPAL: return ppps;
       default: return null;
    }
}
```

**Question:** Here I see three variants.

1. Is my understanding of CDI quite wrong?
2. Is this technology (in this implementation) very limited?
3. A solution exists, but I don't see it?

Please, show me the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer is fairly close to being correct except you seem to want a more general solution.  One way to handle it in CDI would be to ensure that every implementation of PaymentStrategy was named.  Then I would change the implementation of your producer this way:

```
@Produces @Preferred @SessionScoped
public PaymentStrategy getPaymentStrategy(Instance<PaymentStrategy> myInstance) {
  String paymentStrategy = ...;  // Get the name of the payment strategy needed right now

   return myInstance.select(new NamedImpl(paymentStrategy));
}
```

The key part of this solution is the passed in Instance (see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html).  The Instance will contain every implementation of PaymentStrategy.  You can then select the correct one based on whatever criteria you choose.  In the example above I chose name, but you could also choose qualifier, or you could iterate through all of the implementations and use some other criteria of your own design to choose the right one for the circumstances.

Here is the implementation of NamedImpl (the AnnotationLiteral I used in the above solution in order to select the service with the proper name):

```
public class NamedImpl extends AnnotationLiteral<Named> implements Named {
    private final String name;

    public NamedImpl(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String value() {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "@Named(" + name + ")";
    }

}
```

I will note that I believe HK2 has a somewhat better version of this with https://hk2.java.net/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/IterableProvider.html since it allows you to associate more metadata with your services and has helper functions like named.  Since you are using GlassFish 4 you can also evaluate HK2 since CDI and HK2 are well integrated together in GlassFish 4.